# How to make kubeadm init work with external CAs?

Tags: kubernetes, certificate-authority, kubeadm

I am trying to bootstrap a Kubernetes cluster using my own Certificate Authorities (CAs). I am following the [Kubernetes Hardening Guide](https://media.defense.gov/2022/Aug/29/2003066362/-1/-1/0/CTR_KUBERNETES_HARDENING_GUIDANCE_1.2_20220829.PDF), which recommends having separate CAs for etcd and the rest of the control plane. In addition to these, I have set up an external CA for the front-proxy certificates, making it a total of three CAs. I used Vault for generating these CAs, utilizing an offline root CA.

Moreover, my cluster is designed to work with an already functioning external etcd cluster.

I followed the [Exernal CA documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#external-ca-mode)  and [PKI requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/certificates/). After generating the certificates and placing them on my control plane node, I have the following directory structure:

```
tree /etc/kubernetes/
/etc/kubernetes/
├── manifests
└── pki
    ├── apiserver.crt
    ├── apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    ├── apiserver-etcd-client.key
    ├── apiserver.key
    ├── apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    ├── apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    ├── ca.crt
    ├── etcd
    │   ├── ca.crt
    │   ├── healthcheck-client.crt
    │   └── healthcheck-client.key
    ├── front-proxy-ca.crt
    ├── front-proxy-client.crt
    └── front-proxy-client.key

4 directories, 13 files
```

Following the [the high availability](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/), I set up my **kubeadm-config.yaml** as follows:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable
controlPlaneEndpoint: "load_balencer_dns_name:6443"
networking:
  podSubnet: "192.168.0.0/16"
etcd:
  external:
    endpoints:
      - "https://ip_node_1:2379"
      - "https://ip_node_2:2379"
      - "https://ip_node_3:2379"
    caFile: "/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt"
    certFile: "/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt"
    keyFile: "/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key"
```

However, when running

```
kubeadm init --config kubeadm-config.yaml --upload-certs --v=6
```

I encountered the following error:

```
I0315 16:38:30.120235   39470 initconfiguration.go:260] loading configuration from "kubeadm-config.yaml"
I0315 16:38:30.121084   39470 initconfiguration.go:122] detected and using CRI socket: unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
I0315 16:38:30.121228   39470 interface.go:432] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I0315 16:38:30.121243   39470 interface.go:437] Default route transits interface "ens18"
I0315 16:38:30.121333   39470 interface.go:209] Interface ens18 is up
I0315 16:38:30.121378   39470 interface.go:257] Interface "ens18" has 2 addresses :[ip].
I0315 16:38:30.121396   39470 interface.go:224] Checking addr  ip/cidr.
I0315 16:38:30.121409   39470 interface.go:231] IP found ip
I0315 16:38:30.121428   39470 interface.go:263] Found valid IPv4 address ip for interface "ens18".
I0315 16:38:30.121437   39470 interface.go:443] Found active IP ip 
I0315 16:38:30.121457   39470 kubelet.go:196] the value of KubeletConfiguration.cgroupDriver is empty; setting it to "systemd"
I0315 16:38:30.127682   39470 version.go:187] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt
I0315 16:38:30.713146   39470 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for CA certificate
I0315 16:38:30.713239   39470 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for API server certificate
I0315 16:38:30.713859   39470 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for API server kubelet client certificate
I0315 16:38:30.714411   39470 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for ca certificate
stat /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf: no such file or directory
the controller-manager.conf file does not exists or it is not valid
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/kubeconfig.ValidateKubeconfigsForExternalCA
    cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/kubeconfig/kubeconfig.go:406
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newInitData
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:368
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func3
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:170
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).InitData
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:183
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:116
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:940
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1068
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:992
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650
```

Upon researching, I found  [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1118543/kubeadm-not-creating-controller-manager-conf-when-using-external-ca) which suggests that, when in external CA mode, other files need to be already configured. However, I wasn't able to confirm this.

I also attempted to split the kubeadm init by running

```
kubeadm init phase kubeconfig controller-manager --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

but I ended up with the same error as before.

My kubeadm, kubelet, kubectl are all version **1.29.2**. I even tried modifying my kubeadm-config file by specifying

```
kubernetesVersion: "1.29.2"
```

but still encountered the same error.

I am now seeking help from the community!

**EDIT:**

I also come across the `--ignore-preflight-errors` argument and try to pass it to my kubeadm init command:

```
kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=All --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Referencing here the workaround by [Lethargos](https://serverfault.com/questions/1118543/kubeadm-not-creating-controller-manager-conf-when-using-external-ca), what they did was let the kubeadm to create the internal certificates for the cluster itself, while the certificates for etcd will be issued by the vault. They injected the etcd certificates in the cloudinit config files of the controlplane nodes without first having to extract that information from the etcd nodes.

You can try a workaround by creating a manual configuration by creating the missing configuration file, `/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf`, with the necessary parameters referencing the pre-generated certificates for the controller-manager. Then  specify options and references to the API server certificate. Here's a reference [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kube-controller-manager-config.v1alpha1/).

You can try separating `kubeadm init` phases using `kubeadm init phases control-plane --config.yaml` to initialize the control plane without certificate generation by kubeadm. This will create the necessary static Pod manifests in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`, but won't generate certificates or configuration files. After that, manually place the pre-generated certificates in the appropriate locations ( `/etc/kubernetes/pki` ) and create the configuration files like `controller-manager.conf` . Then run `kubeadm init phase kubeconfig --config kubeadm-config.yaml` to generate kubeconfig files based on your existing certificates.